# Form maximize size increasing continuously

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I created a Form. In form load i called a method `Maximize()`.

```
private void Maximize()
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
}
```

I created a button on right top corner which restore/Maximize the form, which calls the `Maximize()` or `Restore()` method where ever necessary by suign some if and else commands.

```
private void Restore()
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

As one may guess, my form starts as a full screen window. When i click the restore button, it restores and then if I again click it, it maximizes again. But as I continue the process, Maximized form size keeps on increasing. I can see that because my Restore button, kept on the right top corner, keeps on hiding on every subsiquent maximize of the form but nomal form size is as it should be.

My question can be confusing, so let me know if its not clear, and also I can upoad the screen shots of the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to post better repro code.  At least something that shows how the button stays in the upper right corner.

Comment: Put a label on your form, and in the Maximize method, add `label1.Text = this.Size.ToString();`  I'm guessing it's not getting larger.

Comment: yes, you are right, form size is not increasing. I figured it out, its because of some anchor and text alignment property. I suggest to close this question or I will delete it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error solved. In my case, form size was not increasing. I figured it out, its because of some anchor and text alignment property. Thanks.